# Can static variables in member functions be thread safe?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am implementing something very similar to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15252842/is-a-bad-practice-to-declare-static-variables-into-functions-member-functions).

```
Window::Window()
{
  static bool flagInit = true;
  if (flagInit)
  {
    doInit(); // doInit should be called only once. 
    flagInit = false;
  }  
  createWindow()
}
```

I understand that using static variables can generally be a bad idea when it comes to multithreading. If two threads create `Window` instance at the same time, `flagInit` might fail to work due to data race.  But Singleton class won't do me the job either, since I want to create multiple instance of the class.

```
Window toolTip, mainWindow;
```

If I add a mutex to the initialization part, does that make it thread safe? Also, is that a good pratice to do so?

```
Window::Window()
{
  {
    std::scoped_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex);
    static bool flagInit = true;
    if (flagInit)
    {
      doInit(); // doInit should be called only once. 
      flagInit = false;
    }  
  }
  createWindow()
}
```

PS `doInit()` comes from someone else's library so I cannot do anything to it

Comment: Re, "static variables can...be a bad idea when it comes to multithreading." Not _only_ in multi-threaded programs. Static variables also are a hinderance to testing and, to re-useability. I personally use static variables only when I am _forced_ to do so (e.g., in an embedded system where I am prohibited from using the heap) or, in projects so small and so short-lived that I would not be sad if I lost the source code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tool exactly for this: [`std::call_once`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/call_once):

```
class Window
{
  static std::once_flag flagInit;
  // ...
};

Window::Window()
{
  std::call_once(flagInit, doInit); // Note: can throw
  createWindow();
}
```

You can also technically still accomplish this with statics since C++11 made their initialization thread-safe:

```
Window::Window()
{
  static bool flagInit = (doInit(), false);
  createWindow()
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your kind help! Both ways seem very elegant to me. For `static bool flagInit = doInit(), false;` I am not familiar with the grammar here. Could you throw me a link maybe?

Comment: @charliepu123, It's using the [comma operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do). You need some kind of value there because it's initialization, but `doInit` could return `void`, so this ensures there's _some_ value. The type and actual value don't matter since you'll never need to use that variable after. With that said, in C++17, I'd personally go for `[[maybe_unused]] static bool _ = doInit(), false;` or something similar since it puts aside the name and makes it clear the variable is deliberate.